# angularjs and D3 - returning array for Donutchart

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I tried this in controller:

```
var one = 0;
var two = 0;

var array = [{ key:"Discounted", y:one},

{key: "NotDiscounted", y: two }];

$scope.donatdata = function(one,two) {

    var one = one;
    var two = two;

    return  array


    };
```

In markup:

```
<nvd3 options="donutoptions" data="donatdata(30,20)"></nvd3>
```

I keep getting this:

d3.js:672 Error:  attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(NaN,NaN) rotate(…".

and the donut isn't drawn

However, when I do this:

```
  $scope.donatdata = function(one,two) {


    return  [{ key:"Discounted", y:one},

    {key: "NotDiscounted", y: two }];


    };
```

It works! but what happens in console is tons of errors:

[image]

The error is described here: https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.3/docs/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,e,f,g)%7Bf%3Dd%26%26g%3Fg%5B0%5D:a(c,e,f,g);return%20b(f,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%5B%7B%22key%22:%22Discounted%22%7D,%7B%22key%22:%22NotDiscounted%22%7D%5D,%22oldVal%22:%5B%7B%22key%22:%22Discounted%22%7D,%7B%22key%22:%22NotDiscounted%22%7D%5D%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,e,f,g)%7Bf%3Dd%26%26g%3Fg%5B0%5D:a(c,e,f,g);return%20b(f,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%5B%7B%22key%22:%22Discounted%22%7D,%7B%22key%22:%22NotDiscounted%22%7D%5D,%22oldVal%22:%5B%7B%22key%22:%22Discounted%22%7D,%7B%22key%22:%22NotDiscounted%22%7D%5D%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,e,f,g)%7Bf%3Dd%26%26g%3Fg%5B0%5D:a(c,e,f,g);return%20b(f,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%5B%7B%22key%22:%22Discounted%22%7D,%7B%22key%22:%22NotDiscounted%22%7D%5D,%22oldVal%22:%5B%7B%22key%22:%22Discounted%22%7D,%7B%22key%22:%22NotDiscounted%22%7D%5D%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,e,f,g)%7Bf%3Dd%26%26g%3Fg%5B0%5D:a(c,e,f,g);return%20b(f,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%5B%7B%22key%22:%22Discounted%22%7D,%7B%22key%22:%22NotDiscounted%22%7D%5D,%22oldVal%22:%5B%7B%22key%22:%22Discounted%22%7D,%7B%22key%22:%22NotDiscounted%22%7D%5D%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,e,f,g)%7Bf%3Dd%26%26g%3Fg%5B0%5D:a(c,e,f,g);return%20b(f,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%5B%7B%22key%22:%22Discounted%22%7D,%7B%22key%22:%22NotDiscounted%22%7D%5D,%22oldVal%22:%5B%7B%22key%22:%22Discounted%22%7D,%7B%22key%22:%22NotDiscounted%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%5D

but I have no idea how to a workaround!!

How can I solve this? and why in the first approach, the values of one and two weren't changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass an object NOT a function as "data" attribute:

```
<nvd3 options="donutoptions" data="donatdata"></nvd3>
```

in controller:

```
$scope.donatdata = [{ key:"Discounted", y:one}, key: "NotDiscounted", y: two}]
```

If donatdata variable should contain dynamic data (e.g. from database), then populate/change it when needed.